# How to zoom for proportional page elements with calc?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

(This only has to work in Chrome.)

I have some code:

```
<div id="mainFrame">
...
   <div id="content">
   ...
```

with css like:

```
#mainFrame {
    width: 90vw;
}

#content {
    zoom: calc(90vw/859px);
}
```

but unfortunately this isn't calculating. I get "invalid property value" in Chrome. The thing is, I'm not sure why. I know I can fix this with some sort of jQuery .. but I'd rather do it in pure CSS.

1. if I'm doing something wrong, how do I do it right? (again, my problem is specific to only Chrome)
2. if it is for some reason not possible: why? **and** what is the jQuery to keep the `#content` sized relative to the viewport throughout the page view?

*edit*: I no longer need the jQuery for #2, I've found it:

```
$(document).ready(resizeContent);
$(window).resize(resizeContent);

function resizeContent() {
  var res = $(window).width()/(859 * 1.2);
  $("#content").css({'zoom': res});
}
```

*for some reason, using `859 * (1/0.9)` was not working like I would have thought... but this suffices*

So just the explanation will do.

Comment: the proper way is : transform:scale(XX); , zoom will work for older IE. calc() is not usable in this case

Comment: @GCyrillus - I don't know what yo mean by "proper way". I'm not using IE, I suppose you mean that IE has its own way of doing things. However, I looked up `transform` and found the proper format for chrome is `-webkit-transform` like `-webkit-transform:scale( calc(90vw/859px) );`, but this does not work either

Comment: i meant zoom is IE rule wich is nowdays transform:scale();. (you can use a javascript to prefix your rules) transform can only a number value. this would work   width:90%;
  transform:scale(0.859); but won't really be your solution ?

Comment: you are right, it won't really be my solution. First, I am not using IE at all, and have zero interest in changing browsers for this project. Second, as you noticed `transform:scale` doesn't seem to support `calc` in any way.

Comment: back, maybe i was not clear on my first comment. calc()  will return a a value with a unit , scale receive only numbers, there is no compatibilities with result return by calc() anyway. Your CSS used zoom , wich is not a vlid CSS rule, it was an old CSS value for old IEs. I believe some version of IE understands both zoom and scale (8 or 9) ... any how, javascript is your mate for this kind of stuff :)

Comment: AFAIK, the `calc` function always needs spaces around the operators. `calc(90vw / 859px)`. And it's good practice to always provide a fallback in case the calc doesn't work.